# Ошибка линковщика при сборке проекта с glew & glfw

Tags: c, opengl, mingw, линковка

В большинстве руководств к OpenGL используется MS Visual Studio, я же хотел использовать MinGW, мне всё-таки удалось собрать GLFW и GLEW при помощи CMake под MSYS makefiles и потом при помощи make я скомпилировал GLEW и GLFW, однако при компиляции файла с кодом [отсюда](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/ru/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-1-opening-a-window/) я получаю множественные ошибки "неопределённая ссылка на %название_функции_или_константы%". Я искал ответ в google и yandex, прочёл [вики](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/MinGW) по OpenGL и MinGW от khronos, изучил [документацию](http://www.mingw.org/category/wiki/opengl) по использованию OpenGL от проекта MinGW мне ничего не помогает! Я буду очень признателен если Вы укажите на ошибки, и то как их исправить.

При компиляции использую следующие команды:

```
gcc window.c -o window -LC:\MinGW\lib -lglew32 -lglfw3
```

Ошибки

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\cc8wHQGc.o:window.c:(.text+0x121):
  undefined reference to  `glewExperimental'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\cc8wHQGc.o:window.c:(.text+0x127):
  undefined reference to  `glewInit@0'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x127):
  undefined reference to  `CreateDCW@16'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x160):
  undefined reference to  `GetDeviceCaps@8'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x179):
  undefined reference to  `GetDeviceCaps@8'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x1ca):
  undefined reference to  `GetDeviceCaps@8'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x24b):
  undefined reference to  `GetDeviceCaps@8'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x291):
  undefined reference to  `DeleteDC@4'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x9ee):
  undefined reference to  `GetDeviceCaps@8'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0xa07):
  undefined reference to  `GetDeviceCaps@8'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0xe9f):
  undefined reference to  `CreateDCW@16'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0xeba):
  undefined reference to  `GetDeviceGammaRamp@8'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0xec8):
  undefined reference to  `DeleteDC@4'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x100c):
  undefined reference to  `CreateDCW@16'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x1027):
  undefined reference to  `SetDeviceGammaRamp@8'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x1035):
  undefined reference to  `DeleteDC@4'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c:(.text+0x1f3):
  undefined reference to  `CreateDIBSection@24'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c:(.text+0x262):
  undefined reference to  `CreateBitmap@20'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c:(.text+0x28d):
  undefined reference to  `DeleteObject@4'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c:(.text+0x37b):
  undefined reference to  `DeleteObject@4'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c:(.text+0x389):
  undefined reference to  `DeleteObject@4'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c:(.text+0xb55):
  undefined reference to  `CreateRectRgn@16'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c:(.text+0xc2c):
  undefined reference to  `DeleteObject@4'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c:(.text+0x6c4):
  undefined reference to  `DescribePixelFormat@16'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c:(.text+0xbbd):
  undefined reference to  `DescribePixelFormat@16'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c:(.text+0xf46):
  undefined reference to  `SwapBuffers@4'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c:(.text+0x1254):
  undefined reference to  `ChoosePixelFormat@8'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c:(.text+0x126f):
  undefined reference to  `SetPixelFormat@12'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c:(.text+0x1592):
  undefined reference to  `DescribePixelFormat@16'

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c:(.text+0x15d9):
  undefined reference to  `SetPixelFormat@12'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Без конкретных команд компиляции и подробного текста конкретных ошибок помочь вам не получится.

Comment: Подробного текста чего?

Comment: Ошибки. По "неопределённая ссылка на %название_функции_или_константы%" можно сказать только то, что у вас ошибка линковки. А какая именно и из-за чего именно - нельзя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот ответ в помощь тем, кто сталкивался с той же проблемой что и я.

Вот решение проблемы: 
1) Зайдите [сюда](http://repo.msys2.org/mingw/x86_64/) и скачайте уже скомпилированные библиотеки glew & glfw. 
2) Скачайте [установщик](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/) 64-разрядной версии MinGW, и поставьте MinGW. 
3) Распакуйте архивы полученные на шаге 1 в соответствующие директории на диске (*.a - в директорию lib, *.h - в include/GL). 
4) Скомпилируйте исходник по следующему образцу: gcc -LC:\%mingw_dir%\lib -IC:\%mingw_dir%\include code.c -o code.exe -lglfw3 -lglew32 -lgdi32 -lopengl32

Answer (score 1):

```
gcc -LC:\MinGW\lib -IC:\MinGW\include window.c -o window.exe -lglfw3 -lglew32 -lgdi32 -lopengl32
```

Порядок следования библиотек важен!

Comment: Спасибо, это убрало большую часть ошибок, но 2 ещё остались:
`c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\cc7IK1Cl.o:window.c:(.text+0x10d): undefined reference to 'glewExperimental'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\cc7IK1Cl.o:window.c:(.text+0x113): undefined reference to 'glewInit@0'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: А вы не пробовали взять прекомпилированные версии библиотек из [репозитория mingw](http://repo.msys2.org/mingw/x86_64/)?

Comment: [Ошибки](https://yadi.sk/d/0GyqAKjsQfNj0w) не вмещаются (превышение лимита на 1500 символов).

Comment: У меня это не воспроизводиться, но по "undefined reference to  'glewExperimental'" нагуглилось огромное количество решений. В большинстве из них ссылаются на отличия в линковке библиотеки GLEW. Попробуйте использовать `-lglew32s` или передать компилятору параметр `-DGLEW_STATIC`.

Comment: Я смог! @Sergey Gornostaev Огромное спасибо за поддержку. Мне пришлось поставить MinGW для 64-разрядных систем, и используя скомпилированные библиотеки из репозитория MinGW, на который Вы дали ссылку, я запустил код!

Comment: Для людей которые столкнуться с этой проблемой я опубликую ответ.